# how to put asset function in jquery insertafter

Tags: jquery, symfony

I need help understanding the correct syntax for the `asset()` method in jQuery ..

this is my code but it doesn't work:

```
$('<a href="{{ asset(\'uploads/'.$('#matr').'/'.data['path'].'\') }}" ><i class="mdi-file-cloud-download"></i></a>').insertAfter( "#date" );
```

MY first error is .   i must use + but it don't work anyway

```
                `$('<a href="{{ asset(\'uploads/'+$('#matr').val()+'/'+data['path']+'\') }}" ><i class="m`di-file-cloud-download"></i></a>').insertAfter( "#date" );
```

I want that link is : 
http://localhost:8000/uploads/12345678910/94dcdbfae9e7a027d6368539622f0796.pdf

but it became

http://localhost:8000/cat/%7B%7B%20asset('uploads/12345678910/94dcdbfae9e7a027d6368539622f0796.pdf')%20%7D%7D

maybe i can't use asset but i don't know the best way to give url

Comment: What exactly does not work here? Please describe your problem or error more specific.

Comment: don't go correct href link  ..syntax error '/'  ..